# File upload form broken by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Have a really bizarre issue which I can't work out.

Essentially I'm trying to add a file upload form to my existing web app. The markup is super simple at the moment:

```
    <form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
            <label for="imageField"> Image File </label>
            <input id="imageField" type="file" />
            </li><li>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Content" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

And in the head I include two scripts:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyAppLibs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyAppCore.js"></script>
```

`MyAppLibs.js` is a concatenation of several libraries (`knockout js, bootstrap, jquery` to name a few). And MyAppCore contains the actual application logic, ko view models and a websocket client.

What's happening is with both these files inlcuded, the file dialog does not appear in chrome and firefoxx (works fine in IE).

If I remove *either* of these includes the file dialog appears fine in all browsers.

Trying to debug this there are no errors in the console and the css of the form is identical in both cases. Editing the concatenation step I've found is I remove `knockout-2.3.0.js` the dialog works as well.

Any suggestions on how to proceed with debugging this issue? I've searched through the libraries and my own code can can't find anything modifying `input type='file'` elements.

Comment: Many plugins catch the errors and you don't see them. In chrome debugger, there is a "Pause on exceptions" button, if you click it a checkbox "Pause on caught exceptions" appears. Beware, many errors are actually caught (in jQuery for example)

Answer (score 0):

Culprit ended up being:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  if(event.which === 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

No Idea why I had that there or what issue it was solving (I think when I was adding support for touch devices). Still a mystery why commenting out the compiled libraries also fixed the issue, may be related to `hammer js`

Thanks for the advice GôTô